# Displaying of values on barchart

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I've found a couple of similar postings to this topic. But they wasn't helpful for me.

I'm relatively new to Python and Seaborn.

This is my Code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x_axis = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F"]
y_axis = [78.5, 79.6, 81.6, 75.4, 78.3, 79.6]

plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of Classifier')

g=sns.barplot(x_axis, y_axis, color="red")
```

I'm just trying to display the values from the y_axis on top of every bar.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Loop through the patches and annotate the bars.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x_axis = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F"]
y_axis = [78.5, 79.6, 81.6, 75.4, 78.3, 79.6]

plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of Classifier')

g=sns.barplot(x_axis, y_axis, color="red")
ax=g
#annotate axis = seaborn axis
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', xytext=(0, 20),
                textcoords='offset points')
_ = g.set_ylim(0,120) #To make space for the annotations
```

Output:

[image]

---

Using matplotlib v3.4.2 bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x_axis = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F"]
y_axis = [78.5, 79.6, 81.6, 75.4, 78.3, 79.6]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy of Classifier')

g=ax.bar(x_axis, y_axis, color="red")
ax.bar_label(g, padding=10)

_ = ax.set_ylim(0,120) #To make space for the annotations
```

Output:

[image]