# Seaborn countplot -- trouble adding counts to top of bars

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a survey dataset that I'm trying to develop a number of summary bar plots.

I have successfully created the plots (with hatching -- in case I need to publish in black and white)... but, I'd like to add counts to the top of the bars, but can't seem to get this correct.

Notice that code below (see "bar.annotate..."). The code successfully displays the plot but doesn't display the counts at the top of the bars.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot al plt

df = survey['Which of the following best describes your position?'] # it's not a dataframe, but if single columns, it's a series
df = df.rename("Fig01: Which of the following best describes your position?")

# Set style
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

# Make the barplot
#bar = sns.barplot(x=df.index, hue="class", data=df)
bar = sns.countplot(x=df.index, data=df)

bar.set_title("Fig01: Which of the following best describes your position?")

# Define some hatches
#hatches = ['--', '++', 'Xx', '\\', '**', 'oo']
hatches = ['+', 'xx', '\\\\']  # repeating letters increases the density 

# Loop over the bars
for i,thisbar in enumerate(bar.patches):
    # Set a different hatch for each bar
    thisbar.set_hatch(hatches[i])
    bar.annotate('%{:d}'.format(thisbar.get_height()), (thisbar.get_x(), thisbar.get_height()+50))


plt.xticks(rotation=-45)
plt.show()
```

Here's what the output currently looks like (again, I'm trying to get the counts to display at the top of the bars).

[image]

Comment: `thisbar.get_height()+50` <-- you might be placing the text too high up

Comment: @PaulH I think is correct, you can add a little more space at the top of your chart by using set_ylim. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45947197/6361531)

Comment: Thanks, the issues was the +50 -- which was much too large.

Comment: ...now, how to center. I can get the width of the bar, but how would I get the width of the annotated text (to get a true center) -- or would there be a better way?

Comment: The center: `thisbar.get_x() + thisbar.get_width()/2` and use `ha='center'`

Comment: Thank you @PaulH `@Scott Boston` @JohanC -- these were all very good suggestions. I've managed to get the count displayed top-center of these bars.